# Reload Activity From Within A Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

I am working on a app which has several tabs, one of the tabs has a button within in it, when the user clicks the button I need it to reload the activity. Came across some code that reloaded the activity but it did not do it within the tabs.

Hope I have explained the issue well. Not sure placing any code would help.

Comment: Please provide more information, code and explain your problem a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EventBus for this purpose or if you want to write your own code then use `interface` as a callbacks.

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) generally work on *pub/sub* mechanism. So you can publish something from your tabbed `fragment` and your `Activity`(subscriber) will listen to it.